# Using boost::regex to match two whole words

Tags: c++, regex, string, search, boost

This seems like a really simple problem, but regardless of what I try the expression can't read the names.

The task here is to match two strings of random length (someone's name) then an id number after words, in this format: Joe Blow 123-456-678

I'm using boost::regex_search for this.

So far I have tried these expressions and they haven't worked..

```
"\\w{15}? \\s? \\w{15}? \\s? \\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}"

"\\w* \\s \\w* \\s \\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}"

"\\w+ \\s \\w+ \\s \\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}"
```

I tried a few other small variations of that as well but nothing has worked. This is the first time ever using regex, so if some of you are pros and this is stupidly simple, please go easy on me.

Comment: The problem is that all your expressions are demanding 3 spaces between words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
"^[a-zA-Z]+? [a-zA-Z]+? \\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}$"
```

and see if it works or not

Comment: Umm, are you sure the input is in this format? "words words 3digits-3digits-3digits" ?

Comment: That was my mistake. Apparently I was missing a word in my text file, that worked perfectly thank you sir. I apologize. Would you mind explaining what the +? notation means after the [a-zA-Z]